# Why both sexes of the species don't show equal level of Competition?

Tags: evolution, ecology, behaviour

In most species, it is seen that either males or females have evolved to be aggressive towards approaching members of the same species of the same sex and maintaining strict territorial boundaries. The logical explanation is that such behavior is advantageous in the evolutionary context. If you increase competition, then the chance of genes suited to the environment getting passed on increases. Obviously, if one male wards of another male from his territory then the genes possessed by him are positively selected for.

In such a scenario, why haven't both the sexes developed a similar level of aggressive competition (Wouldn't this also increase the chance of genes that are suited to the environment getting passed on?)

Comment: Well if women are competitive, doesn't that mean that they risk dying if this competitive is physical? And if a women dies, she cant pass on her child, and therefore her genes to the next generation right?

Comment: There are so many species that contradict what you're trying to ask I'm afraid. If you have a specific species in mind then the question would be more answerable.

Comment: But what about maternal gene selection? There must have been some way natural selection got around the problem of aggressive competition right? If they competed in a non-aggressive manner, then it would still be an evolutionary advantage, right?

Comment: @ChitinousExoskeleton It sounds like you have an example in mind. What species are you talking about?

Comment: Three-Spined Sticklebacks from Tinbergen's Experiment...

Comment: @ChitinousExoskeleton After making a nest a male wants a female to lay eggs there for him to fertilise and pass on his genes. Why would a male fight a willing female in that situation? And of course the male doesn't want another male to take his hard made nest from him.

Comment: @GoodGravy I'm sorry for the edit saying 'members of the same species of the opposite sex' . I want to know that if males fight each other to promote their genes to be selected, then what is the mechanism for females for the same process. Because, they don't seem to have any...

Comment: @ChitinousExoskeleton So you're looking for examples of competitive female bahaviour in the context of mate selection? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naked_mole-rat#Queen_and_gestation is a pretty brutal example.

Comment: @RoSiv That exact same sentence could be used to explain why males would be non-competitive.

Comment: Why Can't both be competitive? That's all I'm asking. If the males are competitive and its helping them in a way, and females are also competitive in the same population wouldn't it have an evolutionary advantage? (Or vice versa, if females are competitive, shouldn't males also be competitive?)

Comment: @ChitinousExoskeleton [This article](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3826203/) explains the stereotype that I am trying to explain. It is a popular misconception that males are competetive and females passive. [This article](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3391421/figure/RSTB20110280F3/) furthermore shows female armoury and a few have competitive male counterparts too. All the scenarios you mentioned exist in the natural world, and unfortunately the question remains if not unclear, now broad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this discrepancy is mainly a consequence of [Bateman's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bateman%27s_principle). Citing wikipedia:

> Bateman's principle suggests that in most species, variability in reproductive success, or "reproductive variance," is greater in males than in females. This is ultimately a consequent of anisogamy. Females, especially mammalian females, almost always invest more energy into producing offspring than males invest. Bateman's principle anticipated and is consistent with Robert Trivers's theory of Parental investment—in most species females are a limiting factor over which males will compete. This competition results in some males being more successful than others, leading to greater reproductive variance among males than females

Variation in competition abilities for access to a mate is called [sexual selection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexual_selection). As a consequence of Bateman's principle, sexual selection is more common in males than in females. You can split sexual selection into `intra-sexual selection` and `inter-sexual selection`. These terms are poorly chosen IMO. They mean:

- Inter-sexual selection: One gender try to look sexy and the other gender chooses the mate. Fighting to impress females is one type of behaviour that can evolve under inter-sexual selection
- Intra-sexual selection: Individuals of one gender fight for the access to an individual of the other gender. This individual cannot chose who to mate with.

In both case, fighting can be involved. As a consequence, you will see among-males fighting is more common than among-females fighting.

Comment: Thank You, I suppose the question was really unclear, but this is essentially what i wanted to know. Whether its necessary for one of the species to always be less competitive (or as you put it 'to have less reproductive variance) than the other!